# Android Studio - Download documentation does not show up in SDK manager

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to download the documentation for Android Studio, and was told to go to `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools` -> `Documentation for Android SDK` to download the documentation, but there was no such option. Is there another way to download the documentation and use it in Android Studio?